# Calling same property from different classes in Swift?

Tags: swift

If I have two explicit classes that both have the same property name, is there a way to call the property without having to define which class I'm using?

```
class firstClass {
    var name = “Name”

    init…..
}

class secondClass {
    var name = “Another name”

    init….

}


now another function can call

//does not work... I get an error saying AnyObject doesn't have property
func printNameOf(object: AnyObject) {
    println(object.name)
}

//works but my software has a lot of classes, which means a ton of code
func printNameOf(object: AnyObject) {
    if object is firstClass {
        println((object as firstClass).name)
    }

    if object is secondClass {
        println((object as secondClass).name)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this by creating a protocol that both your classes conform to:

```
protocol NameProtocol {
    var name: String {get set}
}

class firstClass: NameProtocol {
    var name = "Name 1"
}

class secondCLass: NameProtocol {
    var name = "Name 2"
}

func printNameOf(obj: NameProtocol) {
    // You know obj has property name
    println(a.name)
}
```

Comment: what if I'm using an Apple supplied function that uses AnyObject?  Is this possible?  printNameOf(obj: AnyObject)  rather than printNameOf(obj: NameProtocol)

Comment: Assuming you can change your class, you could still use the protocol, and then in the function (which I'm assuming your implementing/overriding), you could just check once if the `AnyObject` is a `NameProtocol`.